# OultlinedtextField JetpackCompose

Tags: kotlin

I'm developing an application and I configured the room, but I added some fields to the application and the button is only valid when all the fields are filled in. So far so good, working perfectly.

But now, my biggest challenge, one of the fields I programmed to read barcode with mlkit google, the functionality was implemented, when I click on the button it calls the barcode, reads the barcode and returns the result, but my biggest difficulty is that the field is not validated and the button is not turned on to send the data that was filled in in the other fields. Could someone help me, I'll leave a snippet of the code.

```
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = itemDetails.registerResetCode.replace("", barcodeValue ?: ""),
        onValueChange = { onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(registerResetCode = it)) },
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onFocusChanged {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    scopeScanner.launch { onScanBarcode() }
                    showScannerDialog = true
                    focusManager.clearFocus(force = true)
                }
            },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.codigo_rastreio)) },
        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
        ),
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = true,
        singleLine = true,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large
    )
```

When the field opens and reads the code, it returns with the result, what I hope is that the condition is satisfied for the button to activate and send the data that was filled in in the other fields.